# Why is is this code to write all CSV files to a ZIP file failing?

Tags: php

I created this code for putting all CSV files located in the folder `csvbackup/` into one zip file.

There are no PHP errors and no zip file, only a lot of `<br>` tags and the output "failed". What am I doing wrong?

```
    $timenow = date("Ymd-Gi");
    $timestamp = date_create();
    $timestamp = date_timestamp_get($timestamp);
    $filepath = 'csvbackup/';
    $filename = $timenow.'-'.$timestamp.'.zip';

$zip = new ZipArchive;
if ($zip->open($filepath.$filename) === TRUE) {
            if ($handle = opendir($filepath)) {
             while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
                    if (preg_match('/\.csv$/i', $file)) {
                     $zip->addFile($filepath.$file, $file);
                 }  

             }
            }

    $zip->close();
    echo 'ok';
} else {
    echo 'failed';
}
```

Comment: What does `($filepath.$filename)` contain?

Comment: @Pekka `($filepath.$filename)` = `'csvbackup/'.$timenow.'-'.$timestamp.'.zip'`

Comment: From the manual for zip::open "Returns TRUE on success or the error code." - So, what is the return value of `$zip->open`?

Comment: No, I mean what does it contain? Literally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I missed `ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE`.

`if ($zip->open($filepath.$filename, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) === TRUE) { ...`

**It's working now!**

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for coming back to share your answer. (You can accept it after a time out period)